# As páginas do stackoverflow.pt(excepto Analisar) estão a ser renderizadas no pc como se fosse um smartphone/tablet

Tags: suporte, status-intencional

A partir de certa altura, sem que aparentemente tenha feito algo, as páginas passaram a ser renderizadas como se o acesso fosse através de um smartphone/tablet.

Isso não acontece na página Analisar, no Meta e no stackoverflow.com

Firefox 58.0.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não consigo ver a imagem, mas já verificou no rodapé da pagina se por acaso tem a opção "ver site completo"? Pode ser que tenha clicado sem querer em "movel" e tenha mudado.

Comment: @Articuno, era isso mesmo. Obrigado.

Comment: Uma vez que é esse o caso... [tag:status-intencional] ;)